# Floats in ConTeXt: changing caption name and making the \input command work

Tags: tikz-pgf, floats, captions, context, input

I have defined a new float for logic circuits called `logigram`:

```
\definefloat [logigram] [logigrams]
```

Taking advantage of the modes of ConTeXt (i.e. conditional processing), I am making in parallel a french and English version of my document:

```
\starttext
    \startmode [english]
        \placelogigram [right] {Logigram of a negation} {\input negation.tikz}
        The logic circuit of a negation is the opposite logigram.
    \stopmode

    \starmode [french]
        \placelogigram [right] {Logigramme d'une négation} {\input negation.tikz}
        Le circuit logique d'une négation est le logigramme ci-contre.
    \stopmode
\stoptext
```

Now, I would like `\placelogigram` produce the default caption name "Logigram" in English but "Logigramme" in French.

I noted also that ConTeXt can't find my Tikz picture `negation.tikz.tex` when the command `\input`is used inside `\placelogigram`.
This is the file `negation.tikz.tex`:

```
%\usemodule [tikz]
%\usetikzlibrary [circuits.logic.US]
\starttikzpicture [circuit logic US]
    \node [not gate, point down, draw] at (0, 0) (notGate) {};
    \draw (notGate.input) -- ++(up:0.5) node [above] {$\phi$};
    \draw (notGate.output) -- ++(down:0.5);
\stoptikzpicture
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: Knowing that the French mode loads the French Language, `\setuplabeltext [fr] [logigram=Logigramme]` solves the problem of caption name. It Remains to address the strange behaviour of `\input` inside `\placelogigram`.

Comment: Use `\input filename \relax`

Comment: @Aditya Thanks, `\input filename \relax` works well. I discovered also `\ReadFile {filename}`.

Answer (score 3):

Setting French as the language used while compiling in `french` mode:

```
\startmode [french]
    \language [french]
    \setcharacterspacing [frenchpunctuation]
    \mainlanguage [french]
\stopmode
```

and changing:

```
\definefloat [logigram] [logigrams]
```

to:

```
\definefloat [logigram] [logigrams]
\setuplabeltext [fr] [logigram=Logigramme~]
```

solves the probleme of caption name.

I used `\startplacelogigram ... \stopplacelogigram` instead of `\placelogigram` to get my `\input`:

```
\startmode [english]
    \startplacelogigram [location=right, title={Logigram of a negation.}]
        \input negation.tikz
    \stopplacelogigram
    The logic circuit of a negation is the opposite logigram.
\stopmode

\startmode [french]
    \startplacelogigram [location=right, title={Logigramme d'une négation.}]
        \input negation.tikz
    \stopplacelogigram
    Le circuit logique d'une négation est le logigramme ci-contre.
\stopmode
```

EDIT. As indicated in comments, to avoid `\startplacelogigram ... \stopplacelogigram` use `\input filename \relax` or `\ReadFile {filename}` instead of `\input filename`.